# Samsung printer scan to server

Tags: multi-function-printer

There are 4 Samsung printers-scanners with scan function. I would make that all the Samsung printers can scan to a network drive. The document is scanned and saved on the network drive of the server, this network drive is visible for 50 computers, so we can scan from any of the 50 computers. The problem is I have no idea how to do that.

I have seen that in the menu of the samsung printer there are a function named "scan to pc", when I select this function then you can select either "local pc" or "network pc", but when I select one of them, then appears always the same message: "not available". I've looked everywhere but I have only found how to scan to a local pc, and how to configure the local pc with the easy printer manager, but that does not help me, I would like to configure the printer that we can scan directly to the server's network drive. As I said, I have found nothing that can solve my problem, and the option to scan to e-mail is not good for us, because we would scan to server with network drive. The only thing I know is that it would be a possibility is to use the "LDAP Server" function, but I don't know how that works.

I have found this function under the local samsung printer website with the ip adress of the printer's, there you can configure the printer's settings (sync thru web service), the ldap-server function is under "security" -> "External Authentication Server", -> "LDAP Server". I know that this function can are a possibility to configure the scan to server function because my boss in my company where I momentanly work has said it to me. But he don't know how to configure the scan to server function and so he gave me the job to configure the scan to server function.

Answer (score 0):

Are the printers network connected? If they are not, you will have problems. What model are these printers?

If they are network connected, you can use "scan to pc", where the pc is the server (unless you want to scan to each of the pcs). The server will need to have a folder to scan to. This folder requires read/write access for Everybody.

Scan to email is a different thing, but can also be used. In that case, apart from email addresses, the scanner will need the smtp details of your mail server. If the printer can use LDAP, that makes it easy to enter the users' email addresses. But then, you said you do not want email.

In both cases, the printer will need to be set up so it knows the scan destinations, so the users can select from the front panel display. Do the printers even have a display??

Model number please, if you require more details.

**UPDATE after comments from asker.**

The only manual I have been able to find for your printer is the [User Manual](http://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1020734740.pdf), which is almost useless for setup. The only scan facility it mentions is scanning to USB port. The [specs](http://www.samsung.com/au/consumer/monitor-printer/printer-multifunction/mono-multifunction-printer/SCX-4833FD/XSA) do not say anything about network scanning either.

Try going to the printer's web page (by typing its IP address into your browser). Go through the various tabs and buttons that are visible to find scan setup or network setup. You should be able to point it to the folder on the server.

Comment: The printers are Samsung SCX-483x 5x3x Series.

Comment: Yes i would like to scan to the server with the network drive, then

Comment: all pc's can have access to the network drive of the server, but the printer

Comment: must not scan to a pc, but only to the server

Comment: Yes, the printers are all network connected in the intranet, the intern

Comment: network of the company

Comment: And all printers have a display

Comment: But the problem is, when i select the "scan to pc" option in the display of the printer, then comes a message: "not available"

Comment: I have no idea how to set up the printer's scan destination, in the

Comment: using manual there aren't informations about "scan to pc" function